# How to let React Router v6 respond with 404 status code

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In React Router v5, we could provide a 404 response code in this way :

```
<Route path="*" component={NoMatch} status={404}/>
```

But how can we do it with React Router v6?

Comment: The `react-router-dom` v5 `Route` components don't have a `status` prop, and neither do the v6 `Route` components. Can you clarify the use case? How was this `status` prop being used previously? Can you update your question with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` v5 `Route` components don't have a `status` prop, and neither do the v6 `Route` components. If this is simply passing the `status` prop through to the routed component then in RRDv6 you can pass it directly to the `NoMatch` component as a prop.

```
<Route
  path="*"
  element={<NoMatch status={404} />}
/>
```